# Mysql resetting id field

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering is it possible to reset `id` field, let's say now i have 5000 records and id is auto incrementing and after some time i deleted some records so now it's going like 
`1, 5, 10, 11, 23` and so on, it's not realy a issue for me, i just wondering is it possible to make all id's go in order 1,2,3,4,5 and so on

Comment: It is possible but you don't want to do that, ever. Forget about "resetting" the id counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you need this? If your ID field unsigned bigint type, than you can have 9223372036854775808 values. Is that not enough for you? But, if you still think this a problem, you should look to stored procedure feature: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html. In the procedure you must compare current record with previous and next one's and shift the ID's if there is a "free" number. In the end of procedure you just can set increment value such like this: ALTER TABLE `table_name` AUTO_INCREMENT = last_record+1. There's no way to do this with MySQL build-in features.

Answer (score 3):

I would first ask why you want them to go in order.  If its just `OCD` then forget about it.  If its for a programmatic reason, you should never be reliant on surrogate keys.  I would recommend you rework your logic so you have some type of natural key, and code around using that.

Comment: that's actualy isn't related to anything i was just playing around with my database and thought of something like that :D